# Wildcards inside htaccess redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wildcard

I need to make a rewrite rule or redirect with a wildcard included in the line.  Here is an example of what i have so far that works for an individual link.

Redirect 301 /actors/hey-steve-dave-454924/  http://www.mydomain.com/

I would like to have something like Redirect 301 /actors/hey-steve-dave-*  , where * redirects anything with the /actors/hey-steve-dave-(any 6 numbers) to the home page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/actors/hey-steve-dave-.*$ http://www.mydomain.com/
```

That's just a wildcard of anything after `hey-steve-dave-`, you can get more specific - this would be exactly 6 numbers and nothing else, with or without the trailing slash:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/actors/hey-steve-dave-\d{6}/?$ http://www.mydomain.com/
```

Comment: Small addition; `RedirectMatch` uses regular expressions, so the "wildcard" is `.*` rather than just `*`

Comment: @fukawi2 Right, I've also added an additional example that's more exact.